# The set of (the?) numbers of the form 2x+1

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

1. The set of the numbers of the form 2x+1 is infinite.
2. The set of numbers of the form 2x+1 is infinite.

That is, should I or shouldn't I put "the" in front of "numbers" ?

Comment: Since _of the form_ is a fixed phrase and requires the article, there's no need for an extra one with _numbers_; that's a dummy variable anyway. All _numbers_ does is identify the domain set as the Integers (or possibly Natural Numbers), which is probably already in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, although I would write it the second way because it drops an unnecessary "the" and makes the sentence read and sound more natural and less contrived.

"The" is the English language's definite article, used to indicate a specific, known individual noun when the reader might otherwise be left in doubt as to which "something" the author is referring to. Here's a simple example:

*A man robbed the store. Then, a man ran away.*

Who ran away? The robber? The clerk? A random bystander? For a reader, there is no way to know for sure. Here, a definite article is called for.

*A man robbed the store. Then, the man ran away.*

Ah. It was the robber who ran away. Because the writer used "the", the implication is that the reader already knows the man who ran away. In this case, it can only be the robber, as he is the only man who has yet been mentioned. In this case, "the" is necessary because it provides essential detail in identifying the man in the second sentence.

In your case, "the" is unnecessary because the numbers you are referring to require no further identification. "Of the form 2x + 1" already serves to identify them precisely, and so dropping the "the" is fine. In the interest of keeping sentences simple to understand, I would never include the "the" in such a case, although it would not be incorrect to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I would regard the second version as correct. The extra "the" is not necessary, similar to how it would be in expressions such as "the number of (the) people who ask questions". However, the "the" at the beginning is not optional: it would be wrong to write "Set of numbers of the form...".